# How can I create a dynamic (Spinner, EditText, EditText, Button) in a GridLayout

Tags: android, sql, database, android-layout

I'm trying to create a Ordering layout. I completely tried to use BaseAdapter and yet don't get the idea of using LayoutInflater

[image: Sample XML]

The picture above shows Spinner, EditText, EditText, and Button which represent Spinner for Item, edittext for Price and  Quantity, and the button for (Insert,Edit,Delete).

The problem is.. if I click the Button, it will display the same views to the next row and Button will be set (Edit) and once I click it.. a way that I can set IDs in the views.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you want to making dynamic generate android widget ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link : http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-dynamic-layout-using-xml-add.html

inflater is just something packaging the layout defined in your xml to coding as an object.